# php setcookie for link

Tags: php, cookies

Here is my code
i have html link like this

```
<a href="property-view-<?php echo $final_url;?>"  target="_blank" id="<?php echo pro_name;?>" onclick="addBuilderUrlToGoogle(<?php echo $propertyid?>);"><?php echo $pro_name;</a>
```

these php values coming from database it has (thousands of) number of results, here i need to set cookie for this links.
If its clicked means i need to store that links in cookie and i need to show last five viewed links in another page.

Comment: You can use sessions for this

Comment: No i need to use only cookies.

Comment: No you don't need. Actually, a cookie-only solution would be quite verbose and lengthy to implement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, you just need to bind the setting of a cookie to the clicking of the link?

If so, you need to add an ID to your `<a>`:

```
<a href="http://www.sarvatma.org/en/" id="mylink">In English</a>
```

Then bind some cookie-setting code to the click event:

(Using jQuery)

```
$("a#mylink").bind("click", function() {
    $.cookie("TR_LNG", "English");
});
```

**Edited.** Set expires time(for example for 30 minutes):

30 minutes is `30 * 60 * 1000` miliseconds. Add that to the current date to specify an expiration date 30 minutes in the future.

```
 var date = new Date();
 var minutes = 30;
 date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
 $.cookie("example", "foo", { expires: date });
```

Comment: how to use this cookie for getting values?

Comment: Using php: $_COOKIE['TR_LNG'] you can get values!

Comment: in this jquery how to set time? @sergio

Comment: Edited the comment, hope it will help you.

Comment: no, in php we are setting some time limit like time()+3600.. like that how to set time limit in jquery @sergio

Comment: Edited again, now hope it is what you asking for)) Write if it help

Answer (score 0):

You don't need cookies for this. If I undertsand your problem, you simply need to keep track of the last N requests to your app from a certain user. You need users to be associated with a *session*, and at the top of each and every page you want to track you need to:

```php
session_start();
$hits = $_SESSION['last_hits'];
array_push($_SESSION['last_hits'], getExternalUrl());
if (count($hits) > 5) {
  array_shift($hits);
}
```

You'd better implement a framework instead of manually adding this snippet at the top of every PHP file. Also note that I used `getExternalUrl()` because if the PHP server is reverse proxied, the request path may not contain the actual URL (not sure what you really need, tough). Appending the page token to the query string may be ok, too, but it all depends on your needs.

Comment: Yes your correct, But problem is this one for not a particular user.Example if searched anything in imdb or flipkart means they will show on your searched contends in that browser. I want like that.@Raffaele

Comment: @user3115202 HTTP sessions don't require users to sign up. Try to study the proposed solution (or just implement it in a couple of scripts) and see how it'll work as you expect